# Краш при запуске андроид проекта

Tags: unity3d

Обновил проект с 2020 версии редактора до 2022. В меню игры заходит, после перехода на сцену боя при отрисовке стека происходит краш. Единственное, что есть это ошибка "Stack trace could not be displayed". В краш-логе не нашел ничего, в последних пунктах происходит трассировка стека:

```
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll:dbghelp.dll (00007FFE195D0000), size: 2285568 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.22621.1
C:\Windows\system32\schannel.DLL:schannel.DLL (00007FFE263D0000), size: 692224 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.22621.1635
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ncrypt.dll:ncrypt.dll (00007FFE26ED0000), size: 188416 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.22621.1485
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\NTASN1.dll:NTASN1.dll (00007FFE26E90000), size: 225280 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.22621.1
C:\Windows\system32\ncryptsslp.dll:ncryptsslp.dll (00007FFE07870000), size: 159744 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.22621.1555

========== OUTPUTTING STACK TRACE ==================

0x00007FFDA19B5018 (FirebaseCppApp-8_7_0) SWIGRegisterStringCallback_FirebaseAnalytics
0x00007FFDA1B92816 (FirebaseCppApp-8_7_0) SWIGRegisterStringCallback_StorageInternal
0x00007FFDA1BA13C6 (FirebaseCppApp-8_7_0) SWIGRegisterStringCallback_StorageInternal
0x00007FFDA1B956FC (FirebaseCppApp-8_7_0) SWIGRegisterStringCallback_StorageInternal
0x00007FFDA1B9B249 (FirebaseCppApp-8_7_0) SWIGRegisterStringCallback_StorageInternal
0x00007FFDA1B037D7 (FirebaseCppApp-8_7_0) SWIGRegisterStringCallback_StorageInternal
0x00007FFDA1B04D3C (FirebaseCppApp-8_7_0) SWIGRegisterStringCallback_StorageInternal
0x00007FFDA1BA3762 (FirebaseCppApp-8_7_0) SWIGRegisterStringCallback_StorageInternal
0x00007FFDA1BA2005 (FirebaseCppApp-8_7_0) SWIGRegisterStringCallback_StorageInternal
0x00007FFDA1BA31AA (FirebaseCppApp-8_7_0) SWIGRegisterStringCallback_StorageInternal
0x00007FFDA1CD2A67 (FirebaseCppApp-8_7_0) SWIGRegisterStringCallback_StorageInternal
0x00007FFDA1CD418A (FirebaseCppApp-8_7_0) SWIGRegisterStringCallback_StorageInternal
0x00007FFDA1A7B945 (FirebaseCppApp-8_7_0) SWIGRegisterStringCallback_StorageInternal
0x00007FFDA1A27358 (FirebaseCppApp-8_7_0) SWIGRegisterStringCallback_StorageInternal
0x00007FFDA1EA381D (FirebaseCppApp-8_7_0) SWIGRegisterStringCallback_StorageInternal
0x00007FFE28EF26AD (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFE2A18A9F8 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart

========== END OF STACKTRACE ===========

A crash has been intercepted by the crash handler. For call stack and other details, see the latest crash report generated in:
 * C:/Users/vsamo/AppData/Local/Temp/Unity/Editor/Crashes
```

Comment: Может быть кто сталкивался с похожей ситуацией, буду рад любой наводке

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)